# ImageMagick convert to psd - file size is too big

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, psd

I would like to convert some stuff to couple of file formats. I have started with simlpe many output such as:

```
convert .... \
... 
-write path/file.pdf \
-write path/file.psd \
path/file.png
```

It generates three files, but the size of them are:

```
pdf - 2.3MB
psd - 12 MB
png - 181 kB
```

I have done some tests and it turned out that the same pdf output I will get by running the convert again on png, but then the size will be **76kB!**:

```
convert file.png file.pdf
```

And now I am looking for some way to achieve smaller size for psd file. Hopefully there is some way ;-)

EDIT:

I have tried this so far:

- added `-depth 8` - it reducud the size to **6MB**
- added compression `compress RLE` - then size shrinked to **3.2MB**

I still have hope that there is something more I can do ;-)

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing a PDF or PSD file you will write multiple images because they both support pages/layers. But when you convert the PNG to a PDF file the result will only contain one page/layer and you will end up with a smaller file.

If you only want to keep the first page or layer you should do the following after you have read the image:

```
 -delete 1--1
```

This will delete all the images from `1` till `-1`. The `-1` index is an alias for the last page/layer. So when you read a single image this will translate to `1`-`0` (the first page/layer is zero) and will do nothing. When you have a file that has 5 pages/layers it will translate to `1`-`4` and remove the last 4 images.

It is also possible that your input files contains a lot of metadata. You could add `-strip` to your command to remove that.

Comment: I see your point but it's not the case. I convert flatten image to all formats, so there is no layers.

Comment: I have updated the answer, you might want to add some file as an example to your post.

Comment: I do not think it's the case. I was actually making a pattern files for clients: programmatically added text and drew some lines, only added one image with logo, but I have just tested without it and the size almost not changed. I have also tried the `-strip` option. I am afraid it's because of poor implementation of RLE compression as pointed out on this forum: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23662